# Scope of LaTeX code

Tags: scoping

In C/C++ or other language, the code and variables have scope. Is this the same in LaTeX?

I struggled to understand the behavior of below code--

```
\documentclass[doubleside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

%% case 1
%%
\lipsum[5]
{
\flushright
\Huge
}

%% case 2
%%
\lipsum[5]
{
\Huge
\flushright
}

%% case 3
%%
\lipsum[5]

{
\Huge
\flushright
}

\end{document}
```

Hope you can understand my difficulty of understanding what I got (maybe it's my familiarity with C/C++ that makes it difficult) --

[image]

Comment: Note if you want to compare with C, remember TeX is a macro expansion language not a compiled language, so it is far closer to the C pre-processor  #define mechanism than it is to C itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

tex has local and global scope as determined by *groups* (`{...}` and `\begin...\end` in your examples (`\begin...\end` forming a group as they are macros that expand to use of the tex primitive `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` group constructs.)

Commands can be defined to have local or global action but the ones you show are local, a global assignment is not restored when the group ends.

However your confusing output is caused by user error, `\flushright` is not intended to be used as a command (the command form is `\raggedleft`) it is the implementation of the start of the `\begin{flushright}  \end{flushright}` environment.

TeX's linebreaking is optimised over a paragraph, using the settings *at the end* of the paragraph.

The important thing here is that (unlike `\raggedleft`) `\flushright` executes `\par` so ends the previous paragraph so:

In the first case the paragraph is finished, and set with normal settings then locally huge font and ragged setting is set up but discarded at `}` before being used.

In the second case `Huge` fonts and baseline is set up, so the paragraph is set with a huge baseline when the `\par` in `\flushright` is executed.

In the third case, the paragraph is set with the normal settings by the implicit `\par` at the blank line, and so the local settings in the following group are not used at all.

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting that with a previous version of `lipsum` the same behavior would not show; it does now because `\lipsum` issues `\par` at the beginning rather than at the end. This can be exemplified by `{\Huge\lipsum[1]\small\par}`, that gives a different result with TL2017 than with the up-to-date version.

Comment: @David: Thanks. Do you mean `\flushright` is correct in syntax but should not be used because of its "incorrect" semantics? But I don't think there is right or wrong semantics of the code itself. It's up to the user of the code. I struggle to understand while we can use `\flushright` without LaTeX complaining it's not intended to be used.

Comment: @Max no `\flushright` should never be used in that form. It is not an error as `\begin{foo}  \end{foo}` is `\begingroup\foo...\endfoo\endgroup`  so `\flushright` needs to be defined to implement `\begin{flushright}`  but you could replace every use of `\flushright` in the above by `\begin{flushright}\end{flushright}` or in fact replace them all by a blank line, and see the same output. the only part of the `\flushright` definition that you are using is `\par`

Comment: @David Thanks, so `\lushright` is a red herring. After some more trial I got what you mean and started to understand LaTeX's behavior. A simpler version of the test code then would be `{\lipsum[5]\Huge\par}`. The spacing in the paragraph before \par is determined by `\Huge`. What's even more non-intuitive though, is that the font size of the "current" paragraph is not determined by `\Huge`!

Comment: @Max the text is set using the locally specified fonts onto a horizontal list: you would expect `aaa \textbf{bbb}   \textit{ccc}` to use roman italic and  bold fonts, not ignore that and use the font at the end of a paragraph! but then this long horizontal list is broken into lines _as a single operation_ at the end of the paragraph so the linespacing that matters is just the one at the end.

Comment: Now it seems to me `{ }` constrains the scope of the code inside. `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` have the same "scoping" effect. The behavior of in-paragraph spacing determined by setting before `\par` but AFTER the paragraph is what's different from other languages. But this is somehow irrelevant to scope.

Comment: the scope affects the settings of tex variables and registers etc, but the outputs are global structures. If you go `aaa {\itshape bbb} ccc`  then the italic font is set in the local scope and just affects bbb but only the font setting is discarded at the `}` the current horizontal list that is being built is a global structure and has roman aaa, italic bbb and roman ccc, then eventually the `\par` primitive will be executed and this global horizontal list will be broken into lines with whatever settings are in place at that point. @Max

Comment: something can not be "after the paragrah" but before `\par` as it is only `\par`  (or end of vbox) that ends paragraphs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88782/discussion-between-max-and-david-carlisle).

Comment: I imagine that if LaTeX were being written today, it would cause an error to use the backslashed-form of environment names. (E.g. in place of `\begin{document} … \end{document}`, writing `\document`, or similarly writing `\itemize`, `\enumerate`, etc.) Or maybe they'd even have different names, with some combination of `@`s and underscores and colons so that no one can type them accidentally. :-)

Comment: Back to the red herring of `\flushright` (it's a **declaration** in LaTeX form), I just read this in _LaTeX - User's Guide and Reference Manual_ - "**Every declaration has a corresponding environment of the same name (without \\)**". Seems the inverse is not necessarily (or always) true.

Comment: @Max yes and no you can, because of that general rule use `\begin{raggedright}...\end{raggedright}` without it raising a tex error but the behaviour, while well defined, is a bit odd because of the end-of-paragraph issues you raise here, so latex provides an environment form that inserts \par and vertical a space so environments `center`, `flushleft` and `flushright`  to match `\centering`, `\raggedright` and `\raggedleft`